# SQL Join left, group by to get Where ID is equal to a particular only

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have an SQL query as below which work perfectly to get my average rate and other values associated with it.

```
  SELECT deal_page.id,
    deal_page.merchant_id,
    deal_page.category_id,
    deal_page.emirate_id,
    deal_page.title,
    deal_page.title,
    deal_page.description,
    deal_page.emirate,
    deal_page.lat,
    deal_page.lng,
    deal_page.address,
    deal_page.thumbnail_name,
    deal_page.price,
    deal_page.created_at,
    AVG(ratings.ratings) AS ratings
FROM deal_page 
LEFT JOIN ratings ON deal_page.id = ratings.deal_id 
GROUP BY deal_page.id 
ORDER BY lat ASC
```

No am trying to get the database to get me the list of where emirate_id on the deal_page is equaled to 2. I tried below query but it gave me an error:

```
SELECT deal_page.id,
    deal_page.merchant_id,
    deal_page.category_id,
    deal_page.emirate_id,
    deal_page.title,
    deal_page.title,
    deal_page.description,
    deal_page.emirate,
    deal_page.lat,
    deal_page.lng,
    deal_page.address,
    deal_page.thumbnail_name,
    deal_page.price,
    deal_page.created_at,
    AVG(ratings.ratings) AS ratings 
FROM deal_page 
LEFT JOIN ratings ON deal_page.id = ratings.deal_id 
GROUP BY deal_page.id 
ORDER BY lat ASC 
WHERE deal_page.emirate_id = 2;
```

The error says: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE deal_page.emirate_id = 2 LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: You can't write SQL in whatever syntax you want, and expect MySQL to understand it.  Follow the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where` should go before aggregation :

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM deal_page dp LEFT JOIN 
     ratings r
     ON dp.id = r.deal_id 
WHERE deal_page.emirate_id = 2
GROUP BY dp.id 
ORDER BY lat ASC ;
```

Note : I have used table alias, so that it is easy to write for column where is coming from & less typing (avoid full table name).